# Another exception was thrown: No TabController for TabBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I am adding bottom tab bar to my flutter app. But after adding the code it is throwing me an error. 
Here is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("Tab App."),
      ),
      drawer: sideDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomTabBar()
    );
  }

  //Bottom Tab Bar
  Widget bottomTabBar(){
    return new TabBarView(

        children:[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          new Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
          new Container(
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
          ),
          new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
    );
  }
```

Here is error:

```
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
flutter: #1      _HomeState.drawerHeader (package:tabApp/screens/home.dart:72:40)
flutter: #2      _HomeState.sideDrawer (package: tabApp/screens/home.dart:91:13)
flutter: #3      _HomeState.build (package:tabApp/screens/home.dart:37:15)
flutter: #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27)
flutter: #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
flutter: #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #17     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #18     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #26     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4965:32)
flutter: #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #42     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #43     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #44     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #45     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #47     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #49     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #50     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #51     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #52     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #53     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #54     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #56     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #57     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #58     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #59     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #60     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #61     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #62     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #63     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #64     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #66     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #67     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #68     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #69     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #70     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #72     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #73     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #74     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #75     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #76     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #77     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #80     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #84     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #85     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #86     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #88     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #89     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #90     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #91     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #92     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #93     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #94     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #95     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #96     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #97     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #98     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #99     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #100    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #101    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #102    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #104    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
flutter: #105    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #107    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #108    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #109    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #110    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #111    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #115    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #116    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #117    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #118    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #119    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #120    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #121    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #122    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #123    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #124    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #125    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #126    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
flutter: #127    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4643:32)
flutter: #128    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4975:17)
flutter: #129    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #130    _TheatreElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:507:16)
flutter: #131    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #132    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #133    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #134    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3878:5)
flutter: #135    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #136    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #137    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #138    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3990:5)
flutter: #139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #140    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
flutter: #141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #142    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #143    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #144    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3878:5)
flutter: #145    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #146    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
flutter: #147    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #148    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
flutter: #149    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
flutter: #150    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
flutter: #151    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
flutter: #152    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2286:33)
flutter: #153    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:676:20)
flutter: #154    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
flutter: #155    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
flutter: #156    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
flutter: #157    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
flutter: #158    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
flutter: #159    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: No TabController for TabBarView.
```

Comment: The error is in `sideDrawer`. Please paste the code of `sideDrawer` as well

Comment: @vipinagrahari Here it is: https://www.codepile.net/pile/9OKnMKbG

Comment: As you have already drawer, i suggest to use BottomNavigationBar instead of TabBarView. complete code sample https://github.com/driftycode/emirates-dialer/blob/master/lib/home.dart

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As The Error is Stating you need - `TabController` Edit Your Code as Below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return DefaultTabController(  // Added
      length: 4,  // Added
      initialIndex: 0, //Added
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: new Text("Tab App."),
          ),
          drawer: sideDrawer(context),  // Passed BuildContext in function.
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomTabBar()),
    );
  }

Widget sideDrawer(BuildContext context){ ......
```